# Class cast when calling EJB from WAR

Tags: ejb, war, ear, apache-tomee

I have ear and war deployed separately. In both packages I have (EJB) interfaces attached as jars. The endpoint is being looked up by JNDI but I'm getting class cast exception during method call. Is it because the ObjectA returned by EJB is attached to ear and war in jar? Is ObjectA considered as a different class, because is being read by two different classloaders? The server is tomee, ear is deployed in apps (in tomee.xml ) folder and war in webapps? Should I remove the jar with (ObjectA) from both packages and place it in lib folder of tomee - is it the only option?
Regards, Dawid.

The stacktrace

```
07-Nov-2017 07:43:17.754 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.oscm.ui.common.LoggerInitListener
 java.lang.ClassCastException: org.oscm.internal.vo.VOConfigurationSetting cannot be cast to org.oscm.internal.vo.VOConfigurationSetting
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy232.getVOConfigurationSetting(Unknown Source)
    at org.oscm.ui.common.LoggerInitListener.contextInitialized(LoggerInitListener.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The call:

```
public class LoggerInitListener implements ServletContextListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ConfigurationService service = getConfigurationService();
        filePath = service.getVOConfigurationSetting(
                ConfigurationKey.LOG_FILE_PATH, Configuration.GLOBAL_CONTEXT)
                .getValue();
        ...

    }

    ConfigurationService getConfigurationService() {
        return new ServiceLocator().findService(ConfigurationService.class);
    }
```

The backend:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@Local(ConfigurationServiceLocal.class)
@Remote(ConfigurationService.class)
@Interceptors({ ExceptionMapper.class })
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
@Lock(LockType.READ)
public class ConfigurationServiceBean
        implements ConfigurationService, ConfigurationServiceLocal {
...
    @Override
    public VOConfigurationSetting getVOConfigurationSetting(
            ConfigurationKey informationId, String contextId) {
        ConfigurationSetting setting = getConfigurationSetting(informationId,
                contextId);
        return ConfigurationSettingAssembler.toValueObject(setting);
    }
...
}
```

Interface:

```
@Remote
public interface ConfigurationService {
    VOConfigurationSetting getVOConfigurationSetting(ConfigurationKey var1, String var2);

    void setConfigurationSetting(String var1, String var2);

    boolean isServiceProvider();

    boolean isPaymentInfoAvailable();
}
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to post the full stacktrace and code usage. It's perfectly legal to call an EJB from a WAR

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know it is legal. The call itself work but casting result not.

Comment: Yes that's very strange. Are you absolutely sure `VOConfigurationSetting` is the _exact_ same class file in both archives? I'd extract it from the archives and SHA1 hash it at the command line